# Getting the average returns NAN - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a function called "computeAverageOfNumbers".

Given an array of numbers, "computeAverageOfNumbers" returns their average.

Notes:

- If given an empty array, it should return 0.

Here's my code:

```js
function computeAverageOfNumbers(nums) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    total += nums[i];
  }
  var avg = total / nums.length;
  return avg;
}

var input = [];
var output = computeAverageOfNumbers(input);
console.log(output); // --> returns NaN instead of 0
```

As you can see my code returns NaN when you submit an empty array but works if you put regular array items like `var input = [1,2,3,4,5];`

If given an empty array, it should return 0.

Am I missing something?

Comment: That's the logic part of your program where you have to check before you make any specific decision. for example you may need to to make sure that the provided input is not an empty array and it is an array of numbers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if `nums.length`

```js
function computeAverageOfNumbers(nums) {
  if (nums.length === 0) {
    return 0
  } else {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      total += nums[i];
    }
    var avg = total / nums.length;
    return avg;
  }
}

var input = [];
var output = computeAverageOfNumbers(input);
console.log(output);
input = [2,5,9,13];
output = computeAverageOfNumbers(input);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do below

```
if( nums.length == 0 ) return 0;
```

in code

```
function computeAverageOfNumbers(nums) {
  if (nums.length == 0) return 0;
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    total += nums[i];
  }
  var avg = total / nums.length;
  return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your array is empty, nums.length = 0 and a if you divide a number by 0, it gives you NaN.
Just change

`var avg = total / nums.length;`

to

`var avg = (nums.length)?total/nums.length:0`

to solve your trouble

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an empty array then this line:

```
var avg = total / nums.length;
```

Is a division by zero, so avg will be NaN. I would short circuit the function at the start with:

```
if (nums.length === 0)
    return 0;
```

Bear in mind ideally you also want to do some type checking to confirm you've got an array, etc. but the above should give you the basics.

Comment: to be clear, dividing most numbers by `0` yields `Infinity` - except `0 / 0` yields `NaN` (as does `anything falsey / 0`)